# Vue scoped styles: webpack 5 & css-loader 4

Tags: vue.js, webpack, css-loader

I am in the process of upgrading a Vue app to webpack 5 and css-loader 4 (or 5). I use single-file components with `<template>` and `<script>` tags. A handful of my components use scoped styles: `<style scoped>`.

Since upgrading to webpack 5 and css-loader 4, scoped styles from my vue components have been entirely skipped by webpack (as far as I can tell).

My current configuration looks like this:

```js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted here
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { modules: true }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              // enable CSS Modules
              modules: {
                // customize generated class names
                localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:8]'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
  // ... more configuration here
}
```

I've tried an assortment of changes:

- replace `vue-style-loader` with `style-loader`
- add `esModule: false` to the options
- add `ident: 'css-loader-ident'` to the css-loader config (same level as `options`)

So far I have not gotten a webpack config that will inject the styles into the final markup, much less with the vue-component-specific hash.

Ideas?

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI 5?

Comment: @tony19 No, I'm not. This is a vue project about 4 years old that has been upgraded, piecemeal, several times. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution, or one possible solution, is the following:

```js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I found this mostly by trial & error. More info about what's going on/why this works would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same setup and thanks to you I figured it out :)
In my case i just had to switch the order of the loaders:

```
{
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
    ]
},
```