# Vue 3 / Webpack 5 Boilerplate Code Not Applying CSS Scoping

Tags: vuejs3, webpack-5

I'm migrating from my Vue 2 / Webpack 4 setup to Vue 3 / Webpack 5.

Here's my [boilerplate code](https://github.com/jwbats/Vue3Webpack5) on GitHub, so far. It's a VS.NET project, making use of NPM Task Runner to watch and auto-transpile my vue files.

It works for the most part, save for the fact that the CSS isn't properly scoped. It **does** scope the injected CSS (with attributes such as 'data-v-37bfa8da'), but it **doesn't** apply this scoping to the HTML elements.

Ergo, the CSS isn't applied at all.

It **does** get applied when I leave out the 'scoped' attribute in my .vue file's CSS. But then my CSS is global: not scoped at all. But on production, you really do need automated CSS scoping.

I've tried the most often suggested fixes on SO ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66359910/vue-scoped-styles-webpack-5-css-loader-4), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770142/webpack-not-loading-vues-single-file-components-css)), but nothing works:

- set esModule to false in css-loader
- replace vue-style-loader by style-loader
- add '*.vue' to the sideEffects prop in package.json

The first suggestion is currently applied in the GitHub repo's source. The others are not.

Another person, outside of SO, showed me a working setup where he used esbuild-loader. I tried this. Also doesn't work for me.

All packages are up to date. So is my NodeJS.

I don't have so much experience with Webpack. It could be any setting in any package. I could be searching for an answer for a long time.

Is there anybody on here more experienced in Webpack, who is able to find a solution to my problem more quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to add Vue as an external to webpack.config.js.

```
externals: {
    vue: 'Vue'
}
```

Comment: The linked sample source code is updated to contain the bug fix.